# Change default array-type getter Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I found out that there is no way to do this. However, thanks everyone!
[In javascript, can I override the brackets to access characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255041/in-javascript-can-i-override-the-brackets-to-access-characters-in-a-string)

I have something like this:

```
function f() {
    var list = [{name: 'test'}, {name: 'test2'}];
}
```

And I would like to get properties from that list that's inside the function, I think there is some method that overrides default [], but I really don't know what to look for.

```
f[0] // {name: 'test'}
f['test2'] // {name: 'test2'}
```

Comment: You will have to use and implement a separate `get()` method for that.

Comment: If `var list = [{name: 'test'}, {name: 0}];` what would `f[0]` return?

Comment: @dfsq it should not happen, but in case it should return {name: 'test'}

Answer (score 1):

Your `list` variable will be private to `f()` unless you do one of two things.

*First*, you could try returning `list` from `f()` so that you can then get to the properties you need.

```
function f() {
    var list = [{name: 'test'}, {name: 'test2'}];
    return list;
}

var f = f();
f[0] // {name: 'test'};
f['test'] // will return undefined; we'll come back to this
```

*Second*, and I think this option is probably what you're looking for as you tagged the question with 'oop', you could make `f()` a constructor:

```
function f() {
    this.list = [{name: 'test'}, {name: 'test2'}];
}

var f1 = new f();
f1['list'][0] // {name: 'test'};
f1.list[0] // will also return {name: 'test'};
f1.list['test'] // still will return undefined...
```

...

The reason you will not be able to access a value using `['test']` or `['test2']` is because they are your values, whereas ordinarily the values are what we want to access in an object using the key (in this case `['name']` or `.name`). So what you might want is something like this:

```
f1.list[0].name // will return 'test'
f1.list[1].name // will return 'test2'
```

Hope this clears up the confusion.

Comment: I already knew these ways of solving my problem, but they are not exactly what I was looking for. Anyway, thank you, unfortunately I think it's impossible to solve in the way I thought.

Comment: I'm writing a client that uses webSocket to interact with server. The problem is that i have a list of channels(it's similar to IRC) inside an object called ChannelList. That object has inside it a list channels = [] and some methods. Here is a piece of the code, if it can help: http://jsbin.com/isejuh/1/edit

Comment: Okay, so was your question about how to access the `channels` array from outside of the ChannelList function? Or were you trying to rewrite ChannelList so it wasn't using the array but something else instead?

Comment: I edited the question, it's impossible to override the [] accessor, I'll write a function to do what I want, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just use an object instead of an array:

```
var byname = {
    "test": {name: 'test'},
    "test2": {name: 'test2'}
};
// bracket notation:
byname["test2"] // {name: 'test2'}
// dot notation:
byname.test // {name: 'test'}
```

Since you said that you never will access the structure by index, it will be OK to use the unordered key-value-map structure. To save typing, you could create that object dynamically from your array as well:

```
var list = [{name: 'test'}, {name: 'test2'}];

var byname = {};
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    byname[list[i].name] = list[i];
```